# Cross-browser audio problems

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, audio, opera

I'm looking to create an audio player that automatically plays some sounds, which I then control through a control panel. I'm trying to get it to work across browsers but having a massive headache. Any help would be greatly appreciated. There will be multiple sounds, all changeable by a set of plus and minus signs to control the volume, all starting on load and all looping. Again, any help with achieving cross browser/device compatibility would be very much appreciated.

```
 <audio id="player" src="assets/forest_ambience_loop.mp3", "assets/forest_ambience_loop.ogg" autoplay loop;>

    </audio>
    <div>
     <button
     onclick="document.getElementById('player').play()">
     Play
     </button>
     <button
     onclick="document.getElementById('player').pause()">
     Pause
     </button>
     <button
     onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume += 0.1">
     Volume Up
     </button>
     <button
     onclick="document.getElementById('player').volume -= 0.1">
     Volume Down
     </button>
    </div>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about the problem you are having. What browsers have you tested in? Which don't behave the way you expect? How does their behaviour differ from what is desired? What errors are show in their JS consoles?

Comment: I've tested in firefox and chrome, chrome works fine but firefox doesn't do anything. I know this is because firefox needs the .ogg audio, but I'm not sure how to incorporate that into my audio player

Answer (score 1):

`<audio>` tag is incorrect. Try this,

```
<audio id="player" controls autoplay loop>
  <source src="assets/forest_ambience_loop.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  <source src="assets/forest_ambience_loop.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Here is the working demo http://jsfiddle.net/bgCTJ/2/

Comment: Thankyou good sir, and is there anything I need to know to make this work on other browsers other than firefox/chrome? Or mobile devices? 
edit: tried this and it doesn't work in firefox :(